# Cannot read data after updating it in firestore from flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am working with Arduino and flutter app and the communication between them is done through firebase. So basically, the data is sent from Arduino to my laptop via pyserial, and then the update is performed on my computer using python.

For eg, when the user presses a button on the circuit, the python code will edit '1' to the field in firestore. The flutter app will notice the change in the database and after updating it back to 0, it will perform a particular action.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

var callval;
var x1;
var f;
var call;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {


FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('joystick')
    .snapshots()
    .listen((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
  firestoreList = querySnapshot.docs;

  setState(() {
    callval = firestoreList.first.get('call');
  });
  print("call value while listening ${callval}");


  if (x1 == 1 && callval == 0 && f == 0) {
    print("Updated");
    setState(() {
      f = 1;
    });


    //await FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber(num1);
  }

  if (callval == 1) {
    print("call value is 1 ");

    //makecall();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('joystick').doc('data').update(
        {'call': 0});
    setState(() {
       call = firestoreList.first.get('call');
    });
 
    print("Next call value is ${call}");
    setState(() {
      f = 0;
    });

    setState(() {
      x1 = 1;
    });

    if (call == 0) {
      print("updated!");
      callval = 0;
    }
  }




}).onError((e) => print(e));
```

However, when the user pushes the button a second time, the flutter app does update the database but does not show the value being changed from 0 to 1 and then back to 0 (the database value remains 0), on the console of the app. The first time I push the button, the update is performed within some seconds along with the value being changed from 0 to 1 to 0 in the console while the second time, the database is updated within milliseconds but the database value remains 0 on the console and no output message ("updated") is displayed. Hence, the app will neither be able to perform any operation the second time the button is pushed.

When I tried to remove the update and just press some buttons, it reads the different values, but it won't read any updated value while the values are being updated.

Please advise me on how can I debug the issue. I really need help, please.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not using `setState()` to inform the flutter widget tree that the value of callval has changed and the screen needs to be rebuilt.  Try wrapping your assignment of callval in your firebase callback as below.  This should ensure the widget using this value is rebuilt.  (You will also have to be using a statefull widget - I can't see from your code snippet whether you are extending a stateless or statefull widget.)

```
    setState(() {
       callval = firestoreList.first.get('call');
     });
```