# How to efficiently update the firestore while listening to any changes

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update the firestore database every time a change in its value is encountered. I have discussed it in the post

> [Cannot read data after updating it in firestore from flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72204808/cannot-read-data-after-updating-it-in-firestore-from-flutter-app)

but my approach might be wrong. How can I achieve my objective?
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the Documentation of [Stream Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html).
It will help you in this regard...