# Continuously Retrieving data from stream builder

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I am trying to implement stream builder with cloud firestore to retrieve field data.
Here is the code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("test builder"),
      ),
      body:  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('joystick').snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
            if(!snapshot.hasData){
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }

              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i){

                    QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>? ds = snapshot.data?.docs[i];
                    return Text("$snapshot.data?.docs[i].data()!['call']");
                  });


          }
      ),

    );
  }
```

However, it does not output the actual data stored in the database.
I get the following output:

```
AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?
>>(ConnectionState.active,Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot',null, null).data?.docs[i].data()!['call']
```

What should I do to get the data stored in the database? (The field name is 'call')

Comment: Did you consider using `return Text(snapshot.data?.docs[i].data()!['call'])`, so without string interpolation?

Comment: @Carl is this issue resolved?

Comment: @DivyaniYadav nope :(

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it doesn't work :(

Comment: "it doesn't work" is hard to further help with. Keep in mind that we can't see what happens on your system, so you will have to tell us what changed when you updated the code in the way I commented. Was there an error message? Did you run the code in a debugger already, and inspect the variables at each line? If so, what is the *first* line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: I got 3 error messages: 1) "Undefined name '$'. 2) Expected to find ','. 3)Too many positional arguments: 1 expected, but 2 found.

Comment: I am actually trying to read real-time data from firestore and consequently update it back. At first I tried to do something I already discussed on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72204808/cannot-read-data-after-updating-it-in-firestore-from-flutter-app ... then I tried it using streambuilder. But I still could not do it.  Could you please advice me if I am going in a right direction

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement stream builder with cloud firestore to retrieve field data, you  can follow the [StreamBuilder Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)  and [link](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/exploring-streambuilder-in-flutter-5958381bca67) related to explanation of streambuilder in flutter.

As mentioned the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50553853/15774176), you can go through the following code on retrieving data through streambuilder :

> ```
> body: new StreamBuilder( 
>    stream: Firestore.instance.collection("collection").snapshots(), 
>    builder: (context, snapshot) { 
>      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
>    return Text( 'No Data...', ); 
> } 
> else { 
> <DocumentSnapshot> items = snapshot.data.documents; 
> return new Lost_Card( 
> headImageAssetPath : items[0]["url"] ); 
> }
> ```
>
> If you want to create list builder from many documents use it like
> this
>
> ```
> return new ListView.builder( 
> itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length, 
> itemBuilder: (context, index) { 
> DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[index]; 
> return new Lost_Card( 
> headImageAssetPath : ds["url"]; 
> );
> ```

For more information, you can refer to the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) where real time updates with cloud firestore have been explained.

Comment: @Carl Posted an answer is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to return your data

```
return Text(ds['enterYourDataFieldName']);
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to achieve concerns RealTime database, Firestore database is not made for that.

Comment: So, if I want to continuously retrieve data and want to update it on the database in return, I should be using RealTime database?

Comment: Yes,  because it is made for this reason.

Comment: @ⴰⴽⵙⵉⵍⵜⴰⵊⴰⵡⴰⵔⵜ Did you see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).